# Where to find old papers, articles and preprints?

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference

Question: How can I find physics papers, articles and preprints decades ago?

Description: The search of articles and papers is for the purpose of finding interesting phenomenon for a science project. Where can I find a website where physics papers, articles and preprints in the 80's or older could be found?

Comment: You could check out [arxiv.org](http://www.arxiv.org/), they have quite a few old papers as far as I know. Also NASA's [ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html) service. Harvard has a similar one, but I don't remember the link right now. Also, your question will probably be closed, since it's an open ended one. Please read the [faq] for a better list of allowed questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for specific papers then you should be given where to find them, in particular the name of the publication. In order to read most of these you have to pay, or be a member of a University, as a professor or as a student, say. Then you will probably have access to them via the subscription paid by the University.

For some particular examples the author may have a free copy of the paper in his/her website. However this is not the general case, as far as I can tell.

Comment: We have the ID to download full papers, but still thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

For high energy physics, start first by searching the [arxiv](http://arxiv.org).  Sometimes old papers show up there.  Then look on [INSPIRE](http://inspirehep.net) (previously known as the SPIRES database).  Search results from INSPIRE feature links to various websites may be found.  The most useful such links are usually marked 'KEK'.  The Japanese accelerator laboratory KEK has an [archive](http://www-lib.kek.jp/KISS/kiss_prepri.html) of scanned papers.  It's not comprehensive, but it has a lot of stuff -- especially more highly cited papers.  Also, it's free, which is wonderful if you're not at an academic institution with a large budget.